# Why are my java array's not allowing user input for each value?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

The code is supposed to ask for three inputs of each array: (ID, then Name, then Major).

The ID works perfectly, but then when it goes to name, it prints out:

Please enter the student's name: 
Please enter the student's name:

and only allows one input for that line. Then it goes onto Major and works correctly again. So i end up with 3 IDs, 2 names, and 3 majors.

Here is my code:

```
package STUDENT;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentDisplayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long[]studentId = {11, 22, 33};
        String[] studentName = {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"};
        String[] studentMajor = {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"};
        Scanner inReader = new Scanner(System.in);


             /* ----------------------------------------------
            Print the information in the parallel arrays
            ---------------------------------------------- */

        for (int i = 0; i < studentId.length; i++ ){
            System.out.println("Please enter the student's id: ");
            studentId[i] = inReader.nextLong();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < studentName.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter the student's name: ");
            studentName[i] = inReader.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < studentMajor.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter the student's major: ");
            studentMajor[i] = inReader.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < studentId.length; i++ )
        {
            System.out.print( studentId[i] + "\t");   
            System.out.print( studentName[i] + "\t");  
            System.out.print( studentMajor[i] + "\t");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What happens is that `nextLong()` doesn't consume the new-line character `\n` (which is entered when you press <kbd>Intro</kbd>). So, you will have to consume it before you continue with your logic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentId.length; i++ ){
    System.out.println("Please enter the student's id: ");
    studentId[i] = inReader.nextLong();
}

inReader.nextLine(); // ADD THIS

for (int i = 0; i < studentName.length; i++){
    System.out.println("Please enter the student's name: ");
    studentName[i] = inReader.nextLine();
}
```

**Note:** You can read this article, which I wrote some time ago: [[Java] Using `nextInt()` before `nextLine()`](https://christprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/java-common-mistakes-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `inReader.nextLine()`
use `inReader.next()` for String inputs.